# Powershell: Display Errors from Resolve-DnsName

Tags: powershell, hostname

Good morning,

so i got a bunch of IPs and wanted to get the DNS Name,
so i tried this.

`Select-String -Allmatches -pattern '\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}' |% { $_.Matches }| % { $_.Value }| select -Unique| %{Resolve-Dnsname -name $_}`

This works, but when i output it to a file i only get the results where he could find an Hostname.

Is there a method to also display the errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would probably do it this way:

```
Select-String -AllMatches -Pattern '\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}' |
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty Matches |
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty Value -Unique |
    ForEach-Object {
        $Resolve = $null
        $Resolve = Resolve-DnsName -Name $_ -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

        [PSCustomObject]@{
            IP = $_
            Name = $Resolve.Name
            Type = $Resolve.Type
            TTL = $Resolve.TTL
            Section = $Resolve.Section
            NameHost = $Resolve.NameHost
        }
    }
```

You can specify whatever fields you want in the custom object. I have simply included the default properties that `Resolve-DnsName` outputs to the screen.

In general, `Select-Object -ExpandProperty <property>` performs better than `ForEach-Object { $_.<property> }`.

I'm fairly certain the code I have above will work, but there's an outside chance that this:

```
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty Value -Unique |
```

May need to be this:

```
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty Value |
    Select-Object -Unique |
```